# How to loop through the values of the dictionaries which are nested as values in a json file?

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, nested-loops

I'm trying to loop through the values of "Location" key in the dictionaries of the following json file and find the number of entries for a specific location. How could I do that? My loop isn't working properly as it's either counting all the entries regardless what the location is or was ending up with a "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

My code:

```
import requests

def count_jobs_by_location(location):
    api_url = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module%201/Accessing%20Data%20Using%20APIs/jobs.json"
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    if response.ok:
        data = response.json()
        count = 0
        for job in data["jobs"]:
            if job["Location"].lower() == location.lower():
                count += 1
        return count
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `["jobs"]` from the for-loop. You have list of dictionaries so don't use string as an index:

```py
import requests


def count_jobs_by_location(location):
    api_url = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module%201/Accessing%20Data%20Using%20APIs/jobs.json"
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    if response.ok:
        data = response.json()
        count = 0
        for job in data: # <-- remove ["jobs"] here!
            if job["Location"].lower() == location.lower():
                count += 1
        return count

print(count_jobs_by_location("Los Angeles"))
```

Prints:

```
640
```